# hive error: specifying a string in a hive query

Tags: hive

When I run the following hive command

> hive -e 'select msg, count(*) as cnt from table where msg like
>   “%abcd%” group by msg order by cnt desc ;' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' >
>   table.csv

I get the following error.

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:89 cannot recognize input near 'like'
>   '%' 'password' in expression specification

I am aware that there is a problem with specifying the string “%abcd%”. The command works fine in a hive environemnt, but here i was trying to save the result to a csv file. How do i rectify this error?

Comment: The thing is Hive uses single quotes for string so you need to write `like '%abcd%'` and use double quotes for bash string

Comment: @serge_k Tried that as well `hive -e 'select msg, count(*) as cnt from table where msg like '%password%' group by msg order by cnt desc ;' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > table.csv`. But getting the same error.

Comment: However, this worked fine `hive -e "select msg, count(*) as cnt from table where msg like '%password%' group by msg order by cnt desc ;" | sed "s/[\t]/,/g" > table.csv`

Comment: Actually that's what I meant when wrote "use double quotes for bash string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive script should be double-quoted and template is single-quoted:

```
hive -e "select msg, count(*) as cnt from table where msg like '%abcd%' group by msg order by cnt desc ;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > table.csv
```