# Loop through table name in Hive

Tags: shell, hive

I'm trying loop through table name and export the table schema as .csv file.
Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
## declare an array variable
declare -a array=("table1"
                  "table2")

# get length of an array
arraylength=${#array[@]}

# use for loop to read all values and indexes
for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ ));
do
  echo "index: $i, value: ${array[$i]}"
  hive -e $('DESCRIBE FORMATTED ${array[$i]') | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /tmp/${array[$i]}.csv
done
```

But I got this error:

```
test.sh: line 14: DESCRIBE FORMATTED ${array[$i]: command not found
Missing argument for option: e
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: No closing curly brace here `${array[$i]`

Comment: thank you :) but this is not the cause

Comment: If it is not the case, and it is a typo, then fix it in your code and better check how it resolves: just replace the `hive -e` with `echo` and see what it prints

Comment: I think the problem is here:  $('DESCRIBE FORMATTED ${array[$i]'), but I simply can't find the correct way to format this

Comment: But shouldn't it be `${array[$i]}'` instead of `${array[$i]'`  ?? - curly brace is missed at the end

Comment: Yes, you're correct about this. I have corrected the curly brace, but still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, it is one more bug with $(). Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
hive -e $('DESCRIBE FORMATTED ${array[$i]') | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /tmp/${array[$i]}.csv
```

Command substitution `$()` executes shell command but DESCRIBE is not a shell command.
Also curly brace `}` is missing

Fixed:

```
hive -e "DESCRIBE FORMATTED ${array[$i]};" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /tmp/${array[$i]}.csv
```

See example of similar command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541046/2700344

You may need to use $(command) in case if you want to get command result into variable, for example:

```
count=$(hive -e "select count(*) from mytable")
```

In your case you do not need $() command substitution.

Comment: I encounter a new error: 
FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'FORMATTED' '$' '{' in describe statement

Comment: @sealpuppy Try double-quotes in hive command (see updated answer)